# Celery ignores broker URL

Tags: python, flask, celery

I specify the broker URL.

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///persistent/msr.db"
    app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "lelsosecret"
    app.config["CELERY_BROKER_URL"] = "amqp://guest:guest@msr:5672"
    app.config["CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND"] = "db+sqlite:///persistent/msr.db"
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
    db.init_app(app)
    celery.init_app(app)
    return app
```

Over in extensions.py, there is some relevant code.

```
class FlaskCelery(Celery):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FlaskCelery, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.patch_task()
        if "app" in kwargs: self.init_app(kwargs["app"])

    def patch_task(self):
        TaskBase = self.Task
        _celery = self

        class ContextTask(TaskBase):
            abstract = True

            def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                if flask.has_app_context():
                    return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    with _celery.app.app_context():
                        return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.Task = ContextTask

    def init_app(self, app):
        self.app = app
        self.config_from_object(app.config)

auth = HTTPBasicAuth()
celery = FlaskCelery()
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

However, Celery never actually sets the broker URL, no matter what I change it to.

```
Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
```

Docker Compose is running this, that is true. But doing this outside of docker, my old "deeply rooted" structure, never allowed me to change the broker URL, either.

Why might this be?

Comment: What command do you use to run celery? Can you show how you initialize your `celery`  variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `app.config["BROKER_URL"]` rather than `app.config["CELERY_BROKER_URL"]` switched the broker URL for me. I am not sure why this was necessary, or why it even works at all, actually.